# In scala, how do I get access to specific index in tuple?

Tags: scala, tuples

I am implementing function that gets random index and returns the element at random index of tuple.

I know that for tuple like, `val a=(1,2,3)` `a._1=2`

However, when I use random index `val index=random_index(integer that is smaller than size of tuple)`, `a._index` doesnt work.

Comment: You want a collection like a **Vector** instead of a **Tuple**.

Comment: Then in tuple, I can't access random index?

Comment: No, well not out of the box for many reasons. The idea of tuples is that you know how many elements there are _(and they can have different types)_ and each element has some semantic meaning, accessing a random element does not make much sense. You can write a small function that translate some int into one of the fields but again, you probably want to use a collection instead.

Comment: I think my question was different from what I meant.. I edited my question

Comment: Not sure what is the difference?

Comment: I agree with Luis. There is no realistic scenario in which you would ever want to take a random item from a tuple. Tuples are not collections.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`productElement`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Product.html#productElement(n:Int):Any), note that it is zero based and has return type of `Any`:

```
val a=(1,2,3)
a.productElement(1) // returns 2nd element
```

Comment: Note that `2` is returned as a type **Any** so pretty useless.

Comment: @Choi In order to return not just `Any` but `Int` index has to be known at compile time (a tuple could be `(1.0, 2, 3L)`). See details in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you know `random_index` only at runtime the best what you can have is (as **@GuruStron** answered)

```
val a = (1,2,3)
val i = 1
val x = a.productElement(i)
x: Any // 2
```

If you know `random_index` at compile time you can do

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
val a = (1,2,3)
val x = a(1)
x: Int // 2   // not just Any
// a(4) // doesn't compile
val i = 1
// a(i) // doesn't compile
```

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples

Although this `a(1)` seems to be pretty similar to standard `a._1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Scala 3, tuple elements can be accessed in a type-safe fashion (as long as the index is known at compile time) with the `apply` method:

```
val a = (1, 2, 3)
val secondEl = a(1) // result: 2, type: Int
```

If the index is a runtime expression, the returned type will be `Any` instead.