# Is there a non-immutable way to change tuple to list in scala?

Tags: list, scala, tuples

In scala I want to access specific index of tuple without using `tuple._index` form

So I came up with an idea that after changing tuple to list, and then accessing index of list. However, since my project doesn't allow immutable function, I have no idea how to change it. How can I implement the code? Or is there a better way to access specific index of tuple?

Comment: `("first","second").productElement(0)`

Comment: _"since my project doesn't allow immutable function"_ Not sure what you mean with this? Also, if you want to access elements by index and you expect all of them to be of the same type, why are you using a **tuple** in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121418/in-scala-how-do-i-get-access-to-specific-index-in-tuple

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Avoid this type of usage**

You can use this way but you will loose the type which is **not good practice**.

```
(1,2,3,4,5).productIterator.toList
```

or you can do

```
(1,2,3,4,5).productIterator.map[Int](e => e.asInstanceOf[Int]).toList
```

or you can flow @ texasbruce comment

Comment: `.map(e => e.asInstanceOf[Int])).toList` is pretty similar to `.asInstanceOf[Iterator[Int]].toList` or `.toList.asInstanceOf[List[Int]]`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin  yes.

Comment: I mean `asInstanceOf` doesn't do any job at runtime, it just tells the compiler to believe that a type is as written. So in `.map(e => e.asInstanceOf[Int]))` you basically map with identity function at runtime, which is not so effective. Although tuples can't be longer than 22 in Scala 2, so this won't have significant impact.

Comment: @DmytroMitin yes you are right. So I mentioned- it is not good practice, even I never think of use it.